# Need to create subarray based on all common id of the array itself

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
$result=array(
         [0]=>array
         (
            [jobseeker_id] => 85
            [jobtype] => 13
            [sid] => 85
         ))
         [1]=>array
         (
            [jobseeker_id] => 87
            [jobtype] => 11
            [sid] => 87
         ))
         [2]=>array
         (
            [jobseeker_id] => 85
            [jobtype] => 8
            [sid] => 85
         ))

require output=
$result=array(
         [0]=>array
         (
            [0]=>array(
                       [jobseeker_id] => 85
                       [jobtype] => 13
                       [sid] => 85
                      )
            [1]=>array(
                      [jobseeker_id] => 85
                      [jobtype] => 11
                      [sid] => 85
                      )
         [2]=>array
         (
            [jobseeker_id] => 87
            [jobtype] => 8
            [sid] => 87
         ));
```

I want to get the final array with all jobseeker as parent key of it and the jobs in its sub arrays. Like if job seeker 85 has 2 jobs array should be $final_array[85][0] = Job one for 85;
$final_array[85][1] = Job two for 85;
$final_array[51][0] = Job one for 51;
like that

Comment: Please see [ask] and http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: maybe u want to do something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/33905018/1129198

Comment: Can you understand what you have written?

Answer (score 0):

Okay you want "I want to get the final array with all jobseeker as parent key of it and the jobs"
I assume you want jobseaker_id as parent key or the array so you can do like this

```
foreach($oldarray as $key=>$element){
    $result[$element['jobseaker_id']][] = $element;   
}
```

So in this case jobseaker_id = 85 will come to `array([85]=>array([0]=>array([jobseeker_id] => 85)...))`

Comment: please give me full answer because i dont have good understanding of multidimesional array please

Comment: As much as I see difference between this two arrays is that desired one basicly on his [0] has old one so this is how to do this. It is a full answer how to get second one from first one. I dont know what more you need. Be more precise.

Comment: $final_array[85][0] = Job one for 85; $final_array[85][1] = Job two for 85; $final_array[51][0] = Job one for 51;

Comment: $final_array[85][0] = Job one for 85;                                     $final_array[85][1] = Job two for 85;                                  $final_array[51][0] = Job one for 51;  any one help please

Comment: @DineshPithiya check my edit if this is what you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
    // check if jobseeker_id key exists
    if (array_key_exists($item['jobseeker_id'], $result) && is_array($result[$item['jobseeker_id']]) )
        $result[$item['jobseeker_id']][] = $item; // add item to the array with key "jobseeker_id";
    else 
        $result[$item['jobseeker_id']] = array($item); // create key "jobseeker_id" and add item to the new array;
}
```